# How can I account for the midnight time change in this code?

Tags: sql, ms-access, time

I need to define the shift length for 3 different types of shifts: an 8, 10, or 12 hour shift.

**8 hour shift:**

1st shift: 6am-2pm

2nd shift: 2pm-10pm

3rd shift: 10pm-6am

**10 hour shift:**

1st shift: 5am-3pm

2nd shift: 3pm-1am

**12 hour shift:**

1st shift: 3am-3pm

2nd shift: 3pm-3am

The problem is that I'm not sure what is the best way to deal with the midnight changeover. When you do `Datediff("n", #10:00:00:pm#, #06:00:00#)`, it gives a negative value because it thinks you want the time difference from 6am going to 10pm (but with a negative value). This is not what I want.

My code below keeps giving me negative values for the times where it changes over the midnight line.

The extremely tricky part here is that users can submit a `start_time` of, let's say, 2:30:00 AM, which is ***past*** the midnight line. This further complicates things.

How can I make it so that not only does my code return the correct shift length, but also accounts for the possibility of users submitting start times after midnight?

```
(Switch
    (Max([dbo_job.Uf_Shift_Standard])="8",
        (Switch(
            (tbl_OEE.shift = "SH1"),
                Datediff("n", Max([start_time]), [end_time]),
            (tbl_OEE.shift = "SH2"),
                Datediff("n", Max([start_time]), [end_time]),
            True,
                Datediff("n", Max([start_time]), #23:59:59#) + Datediff("n", #00:00:00#, #06:00:00#))),
    Max([dbo_job.Uf_Shift_Standard])="10",
        (Switch(
            (tbl_OEE.shift = "SH1"),
                Datediff("n", Max([start_time]), [end_time]),
            True,
                Datediff("n", Max([start_time]), #23:59:59#) + Datediff("n", #00:00:00#, #01:00:00#))),
    Max([dbo_job.Uf_Shift_Standard])="12",
        (Switch(
            (tbl_OEE.shift = "SH1"),
                Datediff("n", Max([start_time]), #15:00:00#),
            True,
                Datediff("n", Max([start_time]), #23:59:59#) + Datediff("n", #00:00:00#, #03:00:00#)))
    )   
) AS actual_shift_length_minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add 1 (= one day) to the time difference, then calculate it directly using *TimeValue* to remove the date part:

```
ShiftDuration = TimeValue(CDate(#06:00:00 am# - #10:00:00 pm# + 1))
ShiftDuration = TimeValue(CDate(#10:00:00 pm# - #02:00:00 pm# + 1))
ShiftDuration = TimeValue(CDate(#02:00:00 pm# - #06:00:00 am# + 1))
```

All of these will return a date/time value (a timespan) of `08:00:00` which can format for display using *Format* as you like or convert to hours and/or minutes.

If you need to display durations of more than 24 hours, use a function like this:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```